# Application in windows startup does not find SQL Server connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, startup

I have put an application in windows startup that needs an SQL Server connection but when starting it does not find SQL Server connection.
When I close the application and restart it, SQL Server is accessible for the application.
I think that my app starts before SQL Server services, but don't know how to fix the problem. Is any way to start the application after SQL Server services?
(Maybe I have to fix the problem in my codes behind. How?)

Comment: Where is `Sql server` setup?

Comment: @Sham localhost, But in future I have to use it in other servers too.

Comment: Check `Sql server service` status on your machine. It should be running all the time and should not be dependent on the application. Also share the exception text in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that your SQL Server service is not started when your application starts. Increase the connection timeout. You can do this in the connection string so that you don't have to change your code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sql or windows authentification , if it's the first case , try changing it to windows and set the log on to a current local account, reply if it works.

Comment: I was using windows authentication. Problem solved by @RWRkeSBZ answer. Thanks.